# how to use a for loop to iterate through an array inside a function/ class

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class

I cant show the whole code as quite long but here is the over view

x_coord[16] is just an array of size 16 which stores 1,2,3 etc up to 16 - this is inside a class

Basically what I am trying to do is copy the array values from x_coord and make a copy of them inside of the

```
class icon : public pixel 
{
public:
    float Get_x_value();

};



float icon::Get_x_value(){
    return x_coord[16];
}
```

and here is the function I want to copy the x_coord array in

```
icon function(icon& atIcon){

    int x[16];
    for (int i =0; i<16 - 1; i++){
        x[i];  // put here just cause had no idea what else to do mainly to show the bit I dont understand
    cout << x_y_brightness_and_ID_values.Get_x_value() << endl;
    }
return atIcon
}
```

What I dont get is how to loop through the for loop properly and assign the from x_coord to a new array, (the line with x[i]) Any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: X[i] = xxxx; no?

Comment: I have no idea what you try to code. Why you copy the atIcon object? Where is x_coord defined? Why we have x[16] but 0..14 ? And what you mean with "loop through the for loop"?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what your goal is but I'm pretty sure you could just use something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
double a[4] = {2.1,4,1,6.32};

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
std::cout<<a[i]<<std::endl;
}
return 0;
}
```